# In ReactJs is it possible/feasible to perform rendering during a Drag/Drop operation?

Tags: reactjs

In ReactJs is it possible/feasible to perform rendering during a Drag/Drop operation?

The specific use case I had in mind was trying to build a month view calendar in ReactJS that, during dragging of a multi-day event backwards and forward, all the other day events on the calendar would move backwards forward to show (whist the use is still dragging) what the effect would be on all events before the do actually "drop" it.  (i.e. assumes only one event on any given day, so page would aim to move/swap day events around when user is moving one)

Similar to drag dropping a movie clip on a movie timeline, and you see how the clips would swap around during the drag, highlighting what would happen if the user did release the mouse button and do the "drop".

**Question**: Is is this possible/recommend in ReactJS?  If yes, what would be the concept here? i.e. what call would one be making to trigger a "refresh" during the drag event handler?   Or if in the drag event handler you just reposition other components/events does React just render on-the-fly during the drag automatically?

Comment: This could help along with other resources: https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd

Comment: It would be could to try sample react dnd library and tell what issues you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - with an example below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';
import './GcSlider.css';

export class GcSlider extends Component {
  state = {
    value: 50,
  };

  handleChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  buttonClick = (e) => {
    console.log('Button Clicked');
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;

    let divs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map(item => <div className="box {item}">Item {item}</div>)
    console.log('DIVS = ' + divs)

    return (
      <div>  
        <div style={{alignContent:true}}>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="wrapper">
          { divs }
          <div className="box {item}"></div>
          <div className="box {item}">Item B</div>
          <div className="box {item}">Item C</div>
          <div class="overlay" draggable>oevrlay</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GcSlider
```

and css

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  font-size: 150%;
  height: 120px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height:80px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```